# How to add 'now playing' song title info to an rtmp audio stream in ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, rtmp

I am trying to add 'now playing' metadata to a rtmp audio stream using ffmpeg.

My current ffmpeg encoder string looks like this and is working fine, just missing the now playing info:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -re -f dshow -i audio="Line 2 (Virtual Audio Cable)" -acodec libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he_v2 -cutoff 18000 -ab 48k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -f flv "rtmp://blah.com:1935/live/mystream`

The playout software (StationPlaylist) exports the current song title to `C:\NowPlaying\nowplaying.txt` but I have no idea how to get ffmpeg to inject this / keep it up to date.

Any pointers would be great!